# Как заставить процессы CRM Dynamics работать для старых записей?

Tags: crm, workflow, flow

Проблема:
Настроил фоновый процесс в CRM Dynamics 365 Sales который запускается при изменении значения определенного поля. Но оказалось, процесс не запускается, если изменения вносятся в старые записи CRM (которые были созданы до запуска самого процесса).

Вопрос: есть ли какой-то метод как можно заставить CRM запускать процесс даже для старых записей?

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решен. Проблема была в области для которой применяется БП. Надо было проставить Организация вместо Пользователь